# Richer TreeView Experience in VS Code Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to determine if its possible to provide a "richer" experience when using TreeViews in a VS Code extension. The default explorer view has the ability to do things provide custom text coloring for items (such as red when a file has an error or yellow if its been changed). However, the only highlight I can seem to find in TreeItems is only able to highlight text in an item without control over color but only select when the highlight starts/stops.

I would really like to take advantage of the same tree experience provided by the VS Codes extensions view but it does not seem to be restricted by the same API as other extensions (makes sense).

Any recommendations? I am considering just doing a webview that holds my own "TreeView" but wanted to see if there are other options before going down that rabbit hole.

Comment: create a `WebviewView` in the Bar, than you have complete control of what happens in the View